GitHub Actions Fastlane iOS build hangs indefinitely during 'run' step with manual code signing enabled
In my GitHub Actions workflow, I’m using Fastlane to automate the build and deployment process for an iOS app. The workflow hangs indefinitely during the "run script" step when building with Fastlane, specifically in the gym step where manual code signing is configured. Despite specifying the necessary environment variables, keychain setup, and provisioning profile, the build never progresses past the Xcode build phase in GitHub Actions, resulting in a timeout.
The relevant configuration includes:
A Fastlane lane that uses setup_ci(force: true) and match for managing code signing.
gym configured with manual signing style, specifying the provisioning profile and setting DISABLE_PARALLEL_CODE_SIGNING=YES in xcargs.
Clean builds on each run and outputs directed to a specified build directory.
Attempts to troubleshoot included cleaning derived data, verifying the provisioning profile’s UUID, and ensuring the Fastlane environment variables are correctly set, but the issue persists. I would appreciate any guidance on why the build might be stalling or if there are additional configurations needed for GitHub Actions or Fastlane to handle iOS builds with manual code signing.
Fastlane snapshot
Github Actions Logging
